# Mongodb aggregation , group by items for the last 5 days

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to get the result in some form using mongodb aggregation.

here is my sample document in the collection:

```
[{
 "_id": "34243243243",
 "workType": "TESTWORK1",
 "assignedDate":ISODate("2021-02-22T00:00:00Z"),
 "status":"Completed", 
},
{
 "_id": "34243243244",
 "workType": "TESTWORK2",
 "assignedDate":ISODate("2021-02-21T00:00:00Z"),
 "status":"Completed", 
},
{
 "_id": "34243243245",
 "workType": "TESTWORK3",
 "assignedDate":ISODate("2021-02-20T00:00:00Z"),
 "status":"InProgress", 
}...]
```

I need to group  last 5 days data in an array by workType count having staus completed.

Expected result:

```
 {_id: "TESTWORK1" , value: [1,0,4,2,3] ,
     _id: "TESTWORK2" , value: [3,9,,3,5],
     _id : "TESTWORK3", value: [,,,3,5]}
```

Here is what I'm trying to do, but not sure how to get the expected result.

```
db.testcollection.aggregate([
    {$match:{"status":"Completed"}}, 
    {$project: {_id:0, 
            assignedSince:{$divide:[{$subtract:[new Date(),$assignedDate]},86400000]},
            workType:1 
          }
    },
    {$match:{"assignedSince":{"lte":5}}},        
    {$group : { _id:"workType", test :{$push:{day:"$assignedSince"}}}}
    ])
```

result: `{_id:"TESTWORK1": test:[{5},{3}]}` - here I'm getting the day , but I need the count of the workTypes on that day.

Is there any easy way to do this? Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
db.testcollection.aggregate([
    {
        $match: { "status": "Completed" }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            assignedDate: 1,
            assignedSince: {
                $toInt: {
                    $divide: [{ $subtract: [new Date(), "$assignedDate"] }, 86400000]
                }
            },
            workType: 1
        }
    },
    {
        $match: { "assignedSince": { "$lte": 5 } }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                workType: "$workType",
                assignedDate: "$assignedDate"
            },
            count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id.workType",
            values: { $push: "$count" }
        }
    }
]);
```

Comment: Thank you very much Dheemanth, it worked.